# Do the depletion regions meet during pinch off in JFET?

Tags: jfet, depletion-region

In an N-channel JFET, when the voltage across gate and source terminals is 0V and the voltage across drain and source terminals is increased, at a certain voltage (pinch off voltage), the depletion regions appear to touch and the drain current seemingly becomes constant.

The thing I don't understand is, during pinch off, do the depletion regions touch each other or not. When I was studying about it, I came across two explanations,

1. As the channel contains drain resistance and due to the drain current, there is a voltage drop across the channel and if the depletion regions meet, the current drops to zero and there is no voltage drop and the voltage is not conserved hence, the depletion regions appear to meet but they actually don't.
2. During pinch off, the channels do meet and due to the concentration gradient or the voltage gradient the current is able to pass through the depletion region and maintain the voltage drop.

which of the above explanations is true? If it is the first one, what phenomenon are opposing the depletion regions to meet? the explanation makes sense logically but what is happening physically? and why is the drain current constant?

If it is the second one, how can current pass through the depletion region? and if it can, why does it become constant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *(pinch off voltage), the depletion regions appear to touch and the drain current seemingly becomes constant.* Indeed the drain current becomes constant when the JFET is in pinch **off**. What value do you think the drain current has in pinch off? Hint: the word "off" is significant here.

Comment: 1) and 2) are both incorrect. 1) is partly correct, this is the correct part: "As the channel contains drain resistance and due to the drain current, there is a voltage drop across the channel and if the depletion regions meet, the current drops to zero"

Comment: I suggest that you read: https://www.student-circuit.com/learning/year1/semiconductor-devices/jfet-transistor/ and for a more in-depth explanation: https://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/2011/K10147_C010.pdf

Comment: So, from the word pinch off, the word "pinch" means the shape in which the depletion regions contact each other and "off" means that, the voltage (VDS) doesn't have any affect on the drain current?

Comment: *"pinch" means the shape in which the depletion regions contact each other* Yes, in pinch off, the depletion regions touch and partly fuse together. *VDS doesn't have any affect on the drain current?* If the diffusion layers touch, there is no path for the drain current to flow. The JFET is pinched **off** and **no current flows**.

Comment: It is more precise to say "The drain current is zero". If you say "VDS doesn't have any affect on the drain current?" that means the drain current is **constant** and independent of \$V_{DS}\$, which is not the case in pinch off, in pinch off, the drain current is **ZERO**. Maybe you're thinking about \$V_{GS}\$ = 0 which is the situation where the drain current \$I_D\$ is constant and independent of \$V_{DS}\$.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that when the drain to source voltage (VDS) is equal to pinch off voltage (VP), when VGS is maintained constant, pinch off occurs. Isn't that also pinch off?  The depletion regions meet when VDS = VP also right (maintaining constant VGS)? But then the drain current is constant how is that?

Comment: Uhm, no and no and no and also I'm giving up, you need to study the JFET in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it